# Sliding my view controller back in iOS 7 is very slow for only one view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uigesturerecognizer

Has anyone encountered a similar issue? I have one view controller that it lags greatly on the sliding when I pull my finger across the screen to go back, but only on about the first half of the slide. The rest goes smoothly. If so, how does this get counteracted? I honestly can't seem to find anything that might cause it. Even removing all my gesture recognizers does nothing to help it. But other view controllers slide perfectly in my app.

Comment: Please check your viewWillAppear and vieDidLoad method for any operation you are doing on main thread. I think you are blocking your main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say without you being more specific, but it sounds like you might be performing some intensive tasks in the `viewWillAppear:` function of the view controller you're returning to. If the main thread is blocked here, even for a short amount of time, it could result in this behavior.

Comment: It was in `viewWillDisappear` for the view controller being slid, but very close given that I didn't know what to supply!